# SQL doesn't like my R code chunks that include comments

Tags: sql, r, comments

I am trying to run R code in SQL. Generally, it works. However, SQL throws me errors for the lines of code where I have comments.
For example:

This throws me an error:

```
summary(data) # a summary of my data
```

This does not throw me an error:

```
# a summary of my data
summary(data)
```

Does anyone know if there is an option to not have these errors?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: If you're running something like SQL Server's R Services, it would help to see more context of how you're storing and calling the R function and from what SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

> an option to not have these errors

Isn't that exactly what we all wish for? :-)

Hello and welcome to stack overflow. In order to get helpful answers, it is helpful to describe the problem as accurately as possible.

- Which DBMS are you using?
- How is the R code translated into SQL (which package are you using)?
- What does the error message look like?

The comment character # may not be translated correctly to SQL (and # itself is not a comment indicator in SQL). The SQL interpreter probably tries to evaluate the whole line, which obviously does not work.